# 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y' (Forecasting)

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to calculate and plot for the next forecasts for the next 2 years of the series.

Here's my code

```
library(astsa)
data(jj)
Amodel=arima(log(jj),order=c(0,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=4))
plot(Amodel,n1=c(1978,1),n.ahead=8,pch=19,ylab='Log(Earnings)')
```

But Rstudio shows that `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

`arima` returns a list with the model's output. You can view these elements of the list using `names()` and access parts of the model with the `$` operator (i.e. `Amodel$arma`). You will need to decide what part of the model you want to plot, because the `plot()` function will expect a different input then what `arima` provides. Also, `n.ahead` and `n1` are not parameters `plot()` takes.

```
library(astsa)

data(jj)

Amodel <- arima(log(jj),order=c(0,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=4))

names(Amodel) #see parts of the model

plot(Amodel$arma,pch=19,ylab='Log(Earnings)') #plot example - change as you wish
```